# LINQ to SQL query has wrong values in results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have a LINQ query that has the incorrect results, but when I profile the SQL generated, the SQL results are correct.

```
ApplicationsEntities context = new ApplicationsEntities();
var query = from documentation in context.Documnetations
            where documentation.Application_Version_ID == app_ver_id
            orderby documentation.Name
            select documentation;
docs = query.ToList<Documnetation>();
```

I get back two duplicates : "How to install Office 2003" and "How to install office 2003"
[image]

Below is the output of the profiled SQL:
[image]

What could be happening to the assignment of the results from the generated SQL?

Comment: Looks like a undocumented Microsoft feature to prevent people from uninstalling their products. Serious: is the result after ToList() still the same? Maybe the watch is messed up by multiple execution of the underlying query?

Comment: Yes, the toList() has the incorrect results. Even the raw results have the incorrect value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update based on comments**

Your linq query is fine, but in your model you have to set the Primary Key/Entity Key

**Linq-to-Sql**

In your `dbml`, you need to change your primary key from `Application_Version_ID` to `Documentation_Id`

**Linq-to-Entities**

In your `model`, you need to change your entity key from `Application_Version_ID` to `Documentation_Id`

Comment: I won't know the documentation id, only the app version_id.  The sql generated retrieves the correct results.

Comment: @DaveHarding - Your linq query is fine, but in your model you have to set the Primary Key/Entity Key

Comment: that was it. Do you want to post a formal answer and I will accept that?  Thank yo SO much. I was beating my head for HOURS!

Answer (score 0):

**This happens** when the **structure** of one or more **tables** have **changed**.

**Delete** your **tables** and **regenerate** them in your **EDM**. (Entity Data Model)

Right click, `Update Model from Database...`, `Add...`